# Android Market limit from GPRS

Tags: android

What is the exact limit of Android Market for data downloading limit from a cellular card rather than using a WIFI ?

Answer (score 2):

Unlike the App Store, the Android Market imposes no size restrictions to over-the-air downloads, however it seems there is indeed a size limit for Android Market applications, and [it's been increased to 50MB in the new Android Market client update](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/12/android-market-client-update.html), up from 25MB:

> We are also increasing the maximum
> size for .apk files on Market to 50MB,
> to better support richer games.

FYI, the current limit is 25MB. It increases to 50MB with the Market update Google is currently pushing out.

Comment: @HarshaMV Thanks for extended info :)